# Dynamics CRM online Import error, received before Field Mapping

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I was having problems with Dynamics CRM online getting a recordset to import. I have now reduced the problem to one field.

I have a field, named 'Description', a text field that is junking up the works.  When I try the import to CRM online WITHOUT the field, the import goes just fine.  But WITH the field included, I get this message:

[image]

I originally thought that there was a character somewhere in the results of this field that was throwing things off for the import.  So I went through a day long process of doing lots of `REPLACES`, `RTRIM`(ing) and `CAST`.  Nothing worked.

Then I figured, "what if it isn't an odd character?"  and did a `LEFT` with an `RTRIM` function to get me only one character to test the import with. Here is what my final statement looked like when I imported:

```
RTRIM(LEFT(CAST(lntmu11.matter.memo AS varchar(1)), 1)) AS Description
```

So now, I am only returning one character for this column.  I have double checked the output in Excel, and verified that there is no punctuation or odd looking data.  And STILL I am getting the error.

I am exporting from SQL, and the original field is a TEXT datatype field.

Anybody run into a similar problem when importing?  My other thought was that I was exceeding the max individual record size in CRM when I included the Description field in the export.  (Because some of the records would include 500 characters or more).  But now that I am only exporting 1 character, that can't be an issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you not able to download the log file?

Comment: Dave- doesn't look like there is an easy way to do so?  https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/salimadamondynamicscrm/archive/2013/08/14/error-logging-options-in-crm.aspx

Comment: Most times when you get an error like this you can click on the button that says "Download Log File." I see that button is in your screenshot. Is the button disabled?

Comment: unfortunately, yes.  Dammit.

Comment: What is the format of the file you are trying to import?  Have you tried using CSV as well as Office 2007 XML file formats?

Comment: Are there any CRM plugins / workflows attached to the entity which may be running on entity update / create events?

Comment: Throwing a stone in the dark, but save your file in UTF-8 Encoding if it uses a different encoding and try again.

Comment: Could you please confirm that the error occurs when you are uploading the file or juste after uploading it? Also, answering @bluesam question could help us solving your issue.

Comment: this is a generic error that needs additional information.  Specifically, exactly which step in the import process did this occur?  There is nothing inherently wrong with CRM's data import process regarding "Multiple lines of text" fields.  Did you try exporting a template for import on that table and using that to import your data?

Comment: Can you try creating a smaller subset import with different data for the `description` field? Just create some data in Excel and try to import it